BU208A high voltage NPN transistor
I am repairing an old high voltage power supply.  The supply has a step-up transformer with 500V and 20V secondaries.  The 500V is further increased to 1000V with the help of the diode doubler circuit, while 20V is used for powering an opamp based regulator circuit.  The regulator circuit has the BU208A high voltage NPN transistor at its final cascade.  I want to replace this transistor but, unfortunately, cannot find it.  It seems that I can get the BU208D transistor with the integrated diode.  Can the BU208D used instaed of BU208A?  What other transistors could be used instead of BU208A?


TL/DR: Yes
Datasheet
The diode is to protect the transistor against reverse current, for example if it is used in a H-bridge driving an inductive load. In a voltage regulator circuit where the transistor is wired as emitter follower, the diode will protect it against reverse current if the supply is shut down while there is still a charged capacitor on the output. In fact there's probably a diode separate from the transistor to perform this function in your power supply. If you use BU208D it'll probably work fine.
However, if the transistor was killed by a defective driving circuit, replacing it won't fix the problem...

Out of the circuit, the transistor tests fine. However, the power supply continues to blow fuses. This could be related to the inrush current, I used 125 mA fast fuses. I know the fuse must be slow-blow and, according to my calculations, probably 150 - 200 mA with this transformer (26VA, 230V primary, 500V 50 mA secondary 1, 20V 50 mA secondary 2). However, since the BU208A is a high voltage transistor, is there a possibility that it tests fine with a multimeter but fails when 1000V is passed through it?

@Anton if the transistor tests fine (ie you can measure its hFe, the diodes are in the right place etc) then it's probably fine. Transformer inrush is probably what blows your fast fuse, transformers need slow blow especially if there are rectifiers and caps after

I think you haven't a problem with power transistor BU208A you can replace it with BU208D
it is much better to have a diode protection
your problem due to output load in high voltage side, because the load consume more power that what make the fuse to blow out, if so, you must verify your load IE disconnect it and tray again
